# Javascript Regex Replace HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Having a lot of difficulties using regex.

Heres what i am trying to do...

```
text<div> text </div><div> text </div><div> text </div>
```

to turn it in to

```
text<br> text<br>text<br>text
```

I've tryed doing...

```
newhtml = newhtml.replace(/\<div>/g,'<br>');
newhtml = newhtml.replace(/\</div>/g,' ');
```

but this gives the wrong output. Does jquery provide a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want to replace just `div` tags, or any tag?

Comment: just <div> text </div> to <br>text

Comment: Who don't you just replace `<div>` with `<br>`, and remove all the `</div>` left over?

Comment: I meant, replace the string literals, instead of using regexes. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you're escaping the wrong thing, as only the backslash needs to be escaped.

```
newhtml = newhtml.replace(/<div>/g,'<br>');
newhtml = newhtml.replace(/<\/div>/g,' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct, jQuery does provide a better way of doing this.

An [interesting read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)
 first.

Easy, elegant, solution to your specific problem.

```
$('div').replaceWith(function(){
  return "<br>"+$(this).html();
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db7Jm/)

Answer (score 1):

This must do the job:

```
text.replace(/(<\/?\w+?>)\s*?(<\/?\w+?>)|(<\/?\w+?>)/g,'<br>')
```

Though this will only work if there were no tags with some attributes like `<div id="foo1">` 
You do not need to escape `<` as you did in your example, but instead you do need to escape `/`

Comment: adiv>b/div>div>c/div>div>d/div>  thats what that returns

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regexes if you don't need them; just replace string literals.

```
text.replace("<div>","<br>").replace("</div>","");
```

Note: This solution applies exactly to **this** scenario, I don't normally have anything against using regular expresions.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is the following:

```
$('.container').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/<(|\/)div>/g, function(match) {
        return match == '<div>' ? '<br>' : '';
    });
});
```

`/<(|\/)div>/`: Matches `<div>` or `</div>`.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/e5aXY/)

**Note**: `.container` is where your html is placed.

Answer (score 0):

One Liner using JQuery

```
newhtml = $(newhtml ).text().split(' ').join('<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a simple RegExp

`output = inputText.replace(/<\w{0,}\W{0,}>|<\W{0,}\w{1,}>/ig, "With whatever you want it to be replaced with")`

Or you can do this

```
String.prototype.replaceTags = function( replacementText )
{      
    var x = new RegExp( "(" + replacementText + ")+" , "ig");
    return this
           .replace( /<\w{0,}\W{0,}>|<\W{0,}\w{1,}>/ig, replacementText )
           .replace( x, replacementText )  
}
```

And then call it directly on the String as follows

`"text<div> text </div><div> text </div><div> text </div>".replaceTags( "<br>" )`

You'll get this -- `"text<br> text <br> text <br> text <br>"`

This will search for portions in the string which begin with the "<" contains some text in between "div/p/br" additionally if the tag is being ended by "/" and finally the ">" closing of the tag. The ignore case will help when you are not sure that the element is written in Upper or Lower case.