# Function to remove <span></span> from string in an json object array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I know there are many similar questions posted, and have tried a couple solutions, but would really appreciate some guidance with my specific issue.

**I would like to remove the following `HTML markup` from my `string` for each item in my `array`:**

```
<SPAN CLASS="KEYWORDSEARCHTERM"> </SPAN>
```

I have an `array` of `json objects` (printArray) with a printArray.header that might contain the `HTML markup`.

The header text is not always the same.

**Below are 2 examples of what the printArray.header might look like:**

> ```
> <SPAN CLASS="KEYWORDSEARCHTERM">MOST EMPOWERED</SPAN> COMPANIES 2016
>
> RECORD WINE PRICES AT <SPAN CLASS="KEYWORDSEARCHTERM">NEDBANK</SPAN> AUCTION
> ```

I would like the strip the `HTML markup`, leaving me with the following results:

> MOST EMPOWERED COMPANIES 2016
>
> RECORD WINE PRICES AT NEDBANK AUCTION

**Here is my function:**

```
var newHeaderString;
var printArrayWithExtract;
var summaryText;

this.setPrintItems = function(printArray) {
  
  angular.forEach(printArray, function(printItem){

    if (printItem.ArticleText === null) {
      summaryText = '';
    }
    else {
      summaryText =  '... ' + printItem.ArticleText.substring(50, 210) + '...';
    }

// Code to replace the HTML markup in printItem.header
// and return newHeaderString

    printArrayWithExtract.push(
      {
        ArticleText: printItem.ArticleText,
        Summary: summaryText,
        Circulation: printItem.Circulation,
        Headline: newHeaderString,
      }
    );

  });

  return printArrayWithExtract;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function. It will remove all markup tags...

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Call this function sending the html as a string. For example,

```
var str = '<SPAN CLASS="KEYWORDSEARCHTERM">MOST EMPOWERED</SPAN> COMPANIES 2016';
var expectedText = strip(str);
```

Here you find your expected text.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using regular expressions, see below:

```js
var s1 = '<SPAN CLASS="KEYWORDSEARCHTERM">MOST EMPOWERED</SPAN> COMPANIES 2016';
var s2 = 'RECORD WINE PRICES AT <SPAN CLASS="KEYWORDSEARCHTERM">NEDBANK</SPAN> AUCTION';

function removeSpanInText(s) {
  return s.replace(/<\/?SPAN[^>]*>/gi, "");
}

$("#x1").text(removeSpanInText(s1));
$("#x2").text(removeSpanInText(s2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1 ->
<span id="x1"></span>
<br/>2 ->
<span id="x2"></span>
```

For more info, see e.g. [Javascript Regex Replace HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12090672/1220550).
And jQuery is not needed, just used here to show the output.

Answer (score 0):

I used this little replace function:

```
 if (printItem.Headline === null) {
            headlineText = '';
        }
        else {
            var str = printItem.Headline;
            var rem1 = str.replace('<SPAN CLASS="KEYWORDSEARCHTERM">', '');
            var rem2 = rem1.replace('</SPAN>', '');
            var newHeaderString = rem2;
        }
```